# Trying to create a UE4 blueprint or script to recognize set shapes

Tags: c++, software-engineering, game-mechanics, unreal-4, blueprints

I'm currently developing an indie game using Unreal Engine 4 and I've stopped developing it within the last week because I have hit a massive roadblock..

I am trying to figure out how to create a blueprint (or c++ script if necessary) that can have a library of different shapes such as an L (2x1 blocks) in any order which would fit within a 5x5x5 (x,y,z) crafting grid in the game world. See the screenshot with the L shape near the green arrows as a sort of gun object to configure and craft from blocks so long as it matches that particular shape. It's almost like minecraft's crafting system but instead of in the menu this one is on a platform in the game world.

I've tried researching and looking at stuff on youtube and google searching like blueprinting, grid systems, shape systems, crafting systems, building systems, arrays, and now I am thinking maybe I have to use c++ instead just to try to figure out how to make it happen.

Does anyone with more experience on this stuff have any advice or better ideas on how I can create this? Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you rephrase a little bit and correct spelling mistakes, as after reading 3 times I still do not get what you are trying to achieve and what you are stuck on

Comment: sounds a bit like minecrafts crafting grid but supersized, there it's just a list of possible recipes and then matches against them

Comment: @realUser404 sorry, i tried to make it as short and straight forward as I could. I've removed some of the unnecessary stuff to try to explain the problem I am trying to solve better..

Comment: Are you using one 5x5 grid to craft one element or can it be that a 5x5 grid contains multiple elements?

Comment: @realUser404 You are referring to the shape such as an L (2x1 blocks) as the element right? Or? I would just like to make it have one element craftable in the grid at a time because there will be more than one grid platforms available on the map for players to use for building in the game world. However, like minecraft, there would be various recipe shapes to be crafted in the grid.